# Teradata SQL: Calculate number of successive occurrences of error code (and reset on non occurrence)

Tags: sql, teradata, gaps-and-islands

I have a source table that contains run times for several items and resultant error codes during that run. The result I'm looking for should show how many successive runs each error occurs for every item. If the error skips a run, the count resets. Runs are not always run on successive days. The idea is to find out the error codes occur continuously without being reset for every item.

```
Item    Run Run_date    Err_Code
------------------------------------------
A        1  1/1/2020    ERR1
A        1  1/1/2020    ERR2
A        1  1/1/2020    ERR3
A        2  1/2/2020    ERR1
A        2  1/2/2020    ERR2
A        3  1/3/2020    ERR1
A        3  1/3/2020    ERR2
A        4  1/4/2020    ERR2
A        4  1/4/2020    ERR3
A        5  1/5/2020    ERR1
A        5  1/5/2020    ERR3
B..
B..
B..

Result: 3 cols

Item    Err_Cd  Times
---------------------
A       ERR1    3 (meaning ERR1 occurred thrice in succession for A in runs 1,2,3)
A       ERR1    1 (meaning ERR1 occurred once for A in run 5)
A       ERR2    4 (meaning ERR2 occurred 4 times in succession for A in runs 1,2,3,4)
A       ERR3    1 (meaning ERR3 occurred once for A in run 1)
A       ERR3    2 (meaning ERR3 occurred twice in succession for A in runs 4,5)
B..
B..
```

Appreciate any help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subtract `row_number()` from the date and aggregate:

```
select item, err_cd, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by item, err_cd order by run) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by item, err_cd, run - seqnum
order by item, err_cd, min(run);
```

Comment: @user1760691 be sure to mark the answer as correct/accepted if it addressed your question